# Regx Match Expression to find by exlcuding html tags

Tags: c#, regex

```
var TextToFind  = "The Term is Fixed";
var TexToSearch = "<head>The</head> Term is Fixed";
```

The expression used now is `(?mi)\bThe Term is Fixed\b`.

How can we modify this existing expression pattern to find the text with tags?

Comment: Please give few examples

Comment: Added the example by modifying the description. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as follows

```
string str = "< head > The </ head > Term is Fixed";
string textWithoutTags = Regex.Replace(str, "<[^>]*>", string.Empty);
```

Comment: Hi @Harish Shisode Thanks, But we are not suppose to remove/alter the original text, is any way to include this in the expression ?

Answer (score 0):

To match all the substrings you have with tags or whitespace between the words, you may dynamically construct a regex like

```
The(?>\s*<[^>]*>\s*|\s+)Term(?>\s*<[^>]*>\s*|\s+)is(?>\s*<[^>]*>\s*|\s+)Fixed
```

where each space is replaced with `(?>\s*<[^>]*>\s*|\s+)` pattern that matches either

- `\s*<[^>]*>\s*` - `<`, then 0 or more chars other than `<` and `>` and then `>`, enclosed with 0 or more whitespaces
- `|` - or
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fmi%29%5CbThe%28%3F%3E%5Cs*%3C%5B%5E%3E%5D*%3E%5Cs*%7C%5Cs%2B%29Term%28%3F%3E%5Cs*%3C%5B%5E%3E%5D*%3E%5Cs*%7C%5Cs%2B%29is%28%3F%3E%5Cs*%3C%5B%5E%3E%5D*%3E%5Cs*%7C%5Cs%2B%29Fixed%5Cb&i=%3Chead%3EThe%3C%2Fhead%3E%20Term%20is%20Fixed%0D%0A%3Chead%3EThe%3C%2Fhead%3E%20Term%20%3Cspan%3Eis%3C%2Fspan%3E%20Fixed)

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/BxJyLP):

```
var TextToFind  = "The Term is Fixed";
var TexToSearch = "<head>The</head> Term is Fixed\n<head>The</head> Term <span>is</span> Fixed";
var regex = string.Join(@"(?>\s*<[^>]*>\s*|\s+)", TextToFind.Split());
var result = Regex.Matches(TexToSearch, regex).Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value);
foreach (var s in result)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Output:

```
The</head> Term is Fixed
The</head> Term <span>is</span> Fixed
```